# get value from list of select

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, mern

I have list of selection, and I need value of that option. I have coded as below:

HTML code:

```
  <select class="form-select sectionSelect">
      <option value="all_section" data-id="rid0">All Section</option>
      <option value="id1" data-id="rid1">Section 1</option>
      <option value="id2" data-id="rid2">Section 2</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-select sectionSelect">
      <option value="all_section" data-id="rid0">All Section</option>
      <option value="id3" data-id="rid3">Section 3</option>
      <option value="id4" data-id="rid4">Section 4</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-select sectionSelect">
      <option value="all_section" data-id="rid0">All Section</option>
      <option value="id5" data-id="rid5">Section 5</option>
      <option value="id6" data-id="rid6">Section 6</option>
  </select>
```

Jquery code :

```
   $(document).on("change",".sectionSelect",()=>{
    let section_id = $(this).children(":selected").val();
    let room_id = [value of 'data-id' attribute of that option]
    console.log(section_id);
    console.log(room_id);
   })
```

Here, sectionSelect is common class for them all, I have applied on change event on them to detect change. Problem is that I'm getting this object but not able get value of that option.

And one more problem is I also need data-id attribute value of that option.

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).on("change", ".sectionSelect", function() {
  var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);
  let section_id = selectedOption.val();
  let room_id = selectedOption.attr("data-id");
  console.log(section_id);
  console.log(room_id);
})
```

This will give you both the `Id` and `data-id` of the selected option.

**demo**

```js
$(document).on("change", ".sectionSelect", function() {
  var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);
  let section_id = selectedOption.val();
  let room_id = selectedOption.attr("data-id");
  console.log(section_id);
  console.log(room_id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-select sectionSelect">
  <option value="all_section" data-id="rid0">All Section</option>
  <option value="id1" data-id="rid1">Section 1</option>
  <option value="id2" data-id="rid2">Section 2</option>
</select>
<select class="form-select sectionSelect">
  <option value="all_section" data-id="rid0">All Section</option>
  <option value="id3" data-id="rid3">Section 3</option>
  <option value="id4" data-id="rid4">Section 4</option>
</select>
<select class="form-select sectionSelect">
  <option value="all_section" data-id="rid0">All Section</option>
  <option value="id5" data-id="rid5">Section 5</option>
  <option value="id6" data-id="rid6">Section 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks!, It's what I'm saying. It is working here but Not on live server. I'm getting 'selectedOption ' but other values are undefined.

Comment: @DhruvalBhuva Have you checked the console for errors? We can't do much if work here but not on your site, since we can't debug your code

Comment: Yes, you are right, just getting undefined in log